# Create a collage in WPF - fixed position, rotation around center

Tags: c#, wpf

I try to draw different images on a canvas and then save the collage on the canvas as a png file. My problem is that the translation is not right. E.g. when position x is 600 the image is drawn at ~550. Any ideas?

```
        System.Windows.Controls.Image img = new System.Windows.Controls.Image();
        img.Source = new BitmapImage(new System.Uri(System.Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/" + filename, System.UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        img.RenderTransformOrigin = new System.Windows.Point(0.5, 0.5);

        TransformGroup tg = new TransformGroup();
        double scaleX = (double)w / (double)img.Source.Width;
        double scaleY = (double)h / (double)img.Source.Height;
        tg.Children.Add(new ScaleTransform(scaleX, scaleY));
        tg.Children.Add(new RotateTransform(b.Rotation));
        tg.Children.Add(new TranslateTransform(x, y));
        img.RenderTransform = tg;
        canvas.Children.Add(img);

        double dpi = 96d;
        RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap(1700, 1200, dpi, dpi, System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats.Default);
        canvas.UpdateLayout();

        rtb.Render(canvas);

        BitmapEncoder pngEncoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
        pngEncoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(rtb));
        using (var fs = System.IO.File.OpenWrite("test.png"))
        {
            pngEncoder.Save(fs);
        }
```

EDIT: problem happens because of RenderTransformOrigin. How can I rotate around the image center without changing the position?

Comment: Is the TransformGroup applied anywhere? Why are you using a DrawingVisual and VisualBrush, where you could simply call `rtb.Render(canvas)`?

Comment: You are right. `DrawingVisual` is not needed. I removed it. The problem happens as soon as I set the `RenderTransformOrigin`

Comment: Try changing the order of the transforms in the TransformGroup, i.e. first rotate, then translate.

Comment: problem is that the scaletransform is also based on the center

Comment: I can't tell in which order you want to apply those transforms, but translation should usually come last.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was first to do scale, then rotation with pixel based center parameters and then doing the translation. Also `TransformOrigin` should not be set!

```
        System.Windows.Controls.Image img = new System.Windows.Controls.Image();
        img.Source = new BitmapImage(new System.Uri(System.Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/" + filename, System.UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

        TransformGroup tg = new TransformGroup();
        double scaleX = (double)w / (double)img.Source.Width;
        double scaleY = (double)h / (double)img.Source.Height;
        tg.Children.Add(new ScaleTransform(scaleX, scaleY));
        tg.Children.Add(new RotateTransform(b.Rotation, w/2, h/2));
        tg.Children.Add(new TranslateTransform(x, y));
        img.RenderTransform = tg;
        canvas.Children.Add(img);

        double dpi = 96d;
        RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap(1700, 1200, dpi, dpi, System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats.Default);
        canvas.UpdateLayout();

        rtb.Render(canvas);

        BitmapEncoder pngEncoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
        pngEncoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(rtb));
        using (var fs = System.IO.File.OpenWrite("test.png"))
        {
            pngEncoder.Save(fs);
        }
```